# How can I place a view to a particular offset from another view in constrainlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

[image: this picture]

SO, I have two images. one(small) image has to be in the middle to the bottom axis of the second image(smaller), but should be **slightly offset from the Y axis**. I was trying to do this in constraint layout. I know to set the top and bottom constraint of smaller image to the bottom of the bigger image. 
How can I achieve this in constraint layout?
**edit 1 How can i bring the beauty and the beast photo in the above link a litle down to Y axis**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/singapore"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"

        android:src="@drawable/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:src="@drawable/poster"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/singapore">

    </ImageView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: A visual aid of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful

Comment: I also tring marginTop but it was useless  I knew it in cosntraintlayout @sonnet

Comment: Use vertical bias of 0.6 or so

Comment: vertical bias would not work becasue of the constraint set. :/

Comment: @Ashutosh have you tried using guidelines ?

Comment: Thanks @Umair but I liked Cheticamp 's answer more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the top and bottom of the smaller image to the bottom of the larger image vertically centers the smaller image to the bottom edge of the larger image. You can now shift the smaller image down by, say `10dp`, by specifying a translation for the smaller image:

```
android:translationY="10dp"
```

See the description of the y translation property in the [*View documentation*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using **`guidelines`**. In that way you can set your photo where ever you want along side either **`x or y-axis`**.

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70" />  

// app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70"
here you can give the percentage, begining
`or ending of guideline and then add constraint.`
```

So in your  case your code would look something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/singapore"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"

        android:src="@drawable/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poster"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/singapore"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline21">

    </ImageView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```